# File upload twice to different servers?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I want to make two jQuery file upload handlers - one to server1 and the other to server2. Something like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
              url: 'server1',
              type: 'POST',
              autoUpload: true,
              formData: {
                  ....
              }
          })

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                              url: 'server2',
                              type: 'POST',
                              autoUpload: true,
                              disableImageResize: false,
                              imageMaxWidth: 200,
                              imageMaxHeight: 200
                          })
```

However when I do this only the second handler gets called and therefore only the second server receives the file. How can I make both servers receive the file?

UPDATE:

Some people have pointed out these calls are asynchronous which is true - but the callback approach does not work either which is why I need help:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                  url: 'server1',
                  type: 'POST',
                  autoUpload: true,
                  formData: {
                      ....
                  }
              }).on('fileuploadstop', function(){

                             $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                                  url: 'server2',
                                  type: 'POST',
                                  autoUpload: true,
                                  disableImageResize: false,
                                  imageMaxWidth: 200,
                                  imageMaxHeight: 200
                              })
});
```

EDIT 2

I'm still working on this - I'm getting closer but I haven't quite got it.

My goal is when the user adds a file, it gets uploaded to one server, and then immediately to another server with different settings.

Here's a recent implementation - this works the first time, but the second time there are multiple calls to both servers. It appears that even though I am only initializing fileupload() once (with a mutex) and being careful to unset my lifecycle callbacks in the second call, it's still double-triggering the next time someone uploads files. Any ideas?

```
  <form id="form_file_upload" action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>

$(function() {
  $('#fileupload').on('change', function(){
      var fileUploadAddFn = function (e, data) {
          // lifecycle callback
          // do stuff
      };

      var fileSetupFirstUpload = function (){
          $('#fileupload').fileupload( // initialize first server
                  'option',
                  {
                      url: 'server1',
                      type: 'POST'
                  }
          );
          $('#fileupload').on('fileuploadaddfn', fileUploadAddFn); // set a lifecycle callback for 1st upload
      };

      var fileSetupSecondUpload = function() {
          $('#fileupload').fileupload( // initialize first server
                  'option',
                  {
                      url: 'server2',
                      type: 'POST'

                  }
          );
          $('#fileupload').off('fileuploadaddfn');
          $('#fileupload').off('fileuploadstop');
      }

      var filesToUpload = $('#fileupload')[0].files; // this works since fileupload is not yet initialized
      if(typeof fileUploadInitialized == 'undefined'){
          $('#fileupload').fileupload();
          fileUploadInitialized = true; // global mutex to only initialize once
      }

      fileSetupFirstUpload();
      $('#fileupload').on('fileuploadstop', function (e, data) {
        fileSetupSecondUpload();
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesToUpload});
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('send');
      });

      $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesToUpload});
      $('#fileupload').fileupload('send');
  });
```

Comment: These calls are `asynchronous`. The second one is probably starting before the first one is completed, overwriting it.

Comment: when the first upload is done, fire the second through the callback of the 1st

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery file upload - Second upload to different server after first upload completes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696934/jquery-file-upload-second-upload-to-different-server-after-first-upload-comple)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I tried that approach as well, it didn't seem to work

Comment: what does the *console*, say?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides the problem is that I don't know how to "fire the second" as you put it. If I attach the fileupload handler in the callback of the 1st, that doesn't automatically start the upload a 2nd time

Comment: How did you try it if you don't know how to use it? Read on the duplicate link provided by the guy above, it's the `.done` callback mechanism

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Don't know how to use what? See my edits maybe that will help you understand

Comment: Is it possible to upload to a single PHP file so that the user only has to upload the file once... then, the PHP file can upload the file to the second server? Afterwards, the PHP file could then return a JSON string with callback data?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(); // init
$("#fileupload").on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // `File` object reference
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    // settings
    var settings = [{
        "files": file,
        "url": "/echo/json/" // `server1`
        //, additional settings
    }, {
        "files": file,
        "url": "/echo/json/" // `server2`
        //, additional settings
    }];
    var request = function (_settings) {
        var jqxhr = $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', _settings);
        return jqxhr
    };

    $.when.apply($(e.target), // set `this`
        $.map(settings, function (data) {
            return request(data)
            .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // do stuff ,
                // return promise to `then`
                return jqXHR
            })
            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                return errorThrown // return `errorThrown` to `then`
            })
            .complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                /* ... */
            });
        })
    ).then(function (upload1, upload2) {
        console.log(upload1, upload2, this) // `this` : `$("#fileupload")`
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8hms1t4k/

Comment: This DOES seem to work, however as part of my "settings" object I want to specify different imageMaxHeight and imageMaxWidth to each server. Normally when you init fileupload() and pass these settings it processes those resize actions before it actually sends the file. Any idea how I can make the settings work with image resize with your code?

Comment: Tried including `imageMaxHeight` , `imageMaxWidth` properties at `settings` object ?